# Multiple flash embeds on page. Two scenarios. Which is more optimal and efficient?

Tags: video-streaming, flash

I'm working on a project that requires multiple flash movies on a single page. The goal of this project is to create a picture in picture effect using the two different flash movies.

The only two options I see are:

1. Create a new flash movie that embeds two external flash swfs inside of it. Styling will be done through Flash.
2. Embed each flash movie on the page and style using html/css.

My main question is about memory optimization. Which will be more efficient and take less memory?

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question with any authority is likely to be difficult.

However, anything that involves layering something on top of or underneath Flash in an HTML page, like option #2 above, requires you to [embed the SWF](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html) on the page with wmode parameters that can be buggy and less performant (`wmode="transparent"` or `wmode="opaque"`).

The default wmode setting is "window" and this allows Flash to make assumptions about rendering, which should be more optimal performance wise. More importantly, the non-standard wmode's mostly prevent Flash from using hardware acceleration (some browsers can still do it  like IE9 or Safari on Mac because they have support from the OS).

The bugs that occur in the other wmode's vary from browser to browser, but developers often have no choice but to use them. The problems are often subtle, not trying to alarm you.

In terms of memory use, it is likely they will be similar. Regardless of how many SWF's you have on the page (or in other browser tabs/windows), they are all run by the same Flash process.

If you are doing anything with video or Stage3D then layering things on top/underneath of Flash is generally not a great idea. This [article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/video_content_tv.html) has a section titled "Video player and rendering optimizations" that provides good insight on things that can be performance issues. It's referring to the very constrained environment of "TV set top boxes" ... the same considerations apply on a PC we just have more resources to play with.

Not trying to say do it all in Flash. I've worked on a site or two where we didn't do it all in Flash (layered things on video, etc) and it wasn't the end of the world.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and insight. I did not know wmode was not optimal. Based on your answer and reading the documentation, it sounds like doing it all in flash for my specific case would be the best.